# Почему программа выводит ошибку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы

У Олега есть матрица целых чисел N×M. Его очень часто просят узнать сумму всех элементов матрицы в прямоугольнике с левым верхним углом (x1, y1) и правым нижним  (x2, y2). Помогите ему в этом.

Входные данные

В первой строке находится числа N,M размеры матрицы (1≤N,M≤1000) и K - количество запросов (1≤K≤100000). Каждая из следующих N строк содержит по M чисел --- элементы соответствующей строки матрицы (по модулю не превосходят 1000). Последующие K строк содержат по 4 целых числа, разделенных пробелом - x1 y1 x2 y2 --- запрос на сумму элементов матрице в прямоугольнике (1≤x1≤x2≤N,1≤y1≤y2≤M)

Выходные данные

Для каждого запроса на отдельной строке выведите его результат - сумму всех чисел в элементов матрице в прямоугольнике (x1,y1), (x2,y2)

Примеры

входные данные

3 3 2

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

2 2 3 3

1 1 2 3

выходные данные

28

21

У меня получился такой код:

```py
n, m, k = map(int, input().split())
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
b = [0] * (n+2)
for i in range(m+1):
    b[i] = [0] * (n+1)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        b[i+1][j+1] = a[i][j] + b[i][j+1] + b[i+1][j] - b[i][j]
x = []
for i in range(k):
    i1, j1, i2, j2 = map(int, input().split())
    c = b[i2 + 1][j2 + 1] - b[i1][j2 + 1] - b[i2 + 1][j1] + b[i1][j1]
    x.append(c)
print(x, end = '/n')
```

Но в 14 строке код выводит ошибку: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable. С чем это связанно и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индексы выходят за границы списка, ведь в задании они считаются от единицы, а не от нуля

```
c = b[i2][j2] - b[i1-1][j2] - b[i2][j1-1] + b[i1-1][j1-1]
```

И в конце ещё /n замените на \n или вообще уберите

Comment: Спасибо. Но даже так программа не заходит. На каких-то тестах выводит ошибку. Что я не учла?

Comment: Я проверял на ваших данных, вроде больше ничего не правил, выдавало 28 и 21